# Better way of defining the return type of closure function inside typescript .d.ts file

Tags: typescript, types, closures, tsc, .d.ts

I am declaring the function in my typescript definition file .d.ts. It returns a complex predefined object. Need help with the same.

I used the `npx -p typescript tsc src/handler.js --declaration --allowJs --emitDeclarationOnly --outDir types` the kind of command and it gave me a .d.ts file for handler.js to be something like below:

`handler.js`

```
function handler() {
    const myconst = 10;
    function setupHandler (config) {
        config.value = myconst;
        return { ...config }
    }

    function setProcess(cnf) {
       let proc = setupHandler(cnf);
       return true;
    }

    return {
        setup: setupHandler,
        process: {
            set: setProcess,
            options: {
               value: myconst
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My handler.d.ts file generated right now looks like this.

`handler.d.ts`

```
export = handler;
declare function handler(): any;
```

I have tried the following and not sure if this is the right way to get the types being worked right. Any suggestions?

**Goal** I am trying to reach is:

*Create a .d.ts file that will be able to show the return object value/type (predefined) of a closure function. This is mainly for documentation and code intellisense purposes*

```
    export = handler;

    declare function setupHandler(config: any): any;
    declare function setProcess(config: any): any;

    declare interface handlerreturn {
        setup: typeof setupHandler,
        process: {
            set: typeof setProcess,
            options: {
                value: number
            }
        }
     }

    declare function handler(): handlerreturn;
```

Is there any better way of handling this? The function is kept that way since it is a closure function.

**UPDATE on comments:**

The actual file:
https://github.com/cgi-js/cgi-js/blob/main/src/process.js

The config object structure is as in the file `process` attribute object here:
https://github.com/cgi-js/cgi-js/blob/main/src/configs.js

`process.d.ts` (alternate try):

```
export default handler;

export type setup = () => void;
export type setProcess = (config: any) => void;
export type getProcess = () => void;
export type registerHandlers = () => void;
export type exec = () => void;
export type execFile = () => void;
export type fork = () => void;
export type spawn = () => void;
export type executeProcess = () => void;
export type executeAction = () => void;
export type kill = () => void;


export type handlerreturn = {
    set: () => void,
    process: {
        set: setProcess,
        get: getProcess,
        registerHandlers: registerHandlers,
        exec: exec,
        execFile: execFile,
        fork: fork,
        spawn: spawn,
        executeProcess: executeProcess,
        executeAction: executeAction,
        kill: kill,
    }
}


/**
 *
 * handler
 * Process Execution and Management handler
 *
 *
 * @returns { Object } Process module functions
 *      Module Object ==> { Process Object }
 *
 *              setup [function]
 *              process [object]: {
 *                  set [function],
 *                  get [function],
 *                  registerHandlers [function],
 *                  exec [function],
 *                  execFile [function],
 *                  fork [function],
 *                  spawn [function],
 *                  executeProcess [function],
 *                  executeAction [function],
 *                  kill [function]
 *              }
 *
 */
declare function handler(): {
    set: () => void,
    process: {
        set: () => void,
        get: () => void,
        registerHandlers: () => void,
        exec: () => void,
        execFile: () => void,
        fork: () => void,
        spawn: () => void,
        executeProcess: () => void,
        executeAction: () => void,
        kill: () => void,
    }
};

// Alternate process.d.ts file
// declare function handler(): handlerreturn;
```

Comment: If you let the TS compiler infer the type of `handler` you get something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLq44W); if you want to give those currently anonymous types names, you can certainly do so, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1P6yW).  I wouldn't pretend that your module has ambient functions named `setupHandler()` and `setProcess()`.  Does that fully address your question (and I can write an answer) or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you at all concerned about the `any` type for the `config` inputs and function outputs?  Do you have an idea what those config types actually look like?

Comment: @jcalz The `any` type is eased here for explaination. I will have a different type there. But yes, I will be concerned about the config: mytype in real implementation. The config will be a predefined rigid structure that can be assigned with type

Comment: Could you answer the question from my first comment so I know how and whether to proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz thank you so much for your reply. Here is the file - https://github.com/cgi-js/cgi-js/blob/main/src/process.js I have updated this in the question. I have also added two things. I have added jsdoc comments to the code and it seems to be showing up in the intellisense of vscode. I have also added one more try I have made above for the process.js file. Any help is welcome.

Comment: You shouldn't require that people navigate away from Stack Overflow to see  information necessary to answering a question, so you should also include anything relevant as plain text in the body of the question (the link to github is nice to have, but it is not sufficient by itself).  If such code is very long, then remember that you should be providing a [mre] with only the code necessary to answer a version of the question that other people could have also.  SO isn't a code review service, it's more like a FAQ.  Frankly your original example code was more appropriate for an SO question.

Comment: Which leads me to ask again whether my suggestions in your original comment address your question or not. I shouldn't need much more context, unless the issue is so incredibly specific to your particular code base that you'd really be better off getting someone to do code review. There is a codereview stackexchange site, which has [its own rules](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) but it could turn out that you might be looking for that kind of resource instead (again, if you do go that route, please make sure to adhere to their guidelines before posting).

Comment: None of the issue update was for code review. I would not want this to be touched by anyone atleast at the moment. It was for a informed suggestion. I just wanted to know how do I represent complex nested closure returns in types? Any suggestions are welcome. Probably the return of process.js object might be clearer of how the code returns object that needs typing

Comment: Sorry, but I think we're at an impasse.  I still don't know if the suggested code I included in my original comment constituted an answer to your question or if it didn't meet your needs for some reason. I will disengage at this point.  Hopefully you find the help you are looking for.  Good luck!

Comment: No impasse my friend. You still didn't read it right. I just want to know the near okay way of typing the return of process.js nested object (containing functions with returns) which is a closure. Frankly the jsdocs and tsc command that generates type just does this `export = handler; define function handler(): any` which is from ms typescript commandline which is a little annoying since it does not type closure internals and returns. I have to manually do it. This may be a improvement for ms typescript but right now I need my way through. Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 2):

Using `any` essentially defeats the purpose of TypeScript - it's similar to not doing any type-checking at all. Don't use it unless you absolutely have to, which should be almost never.

Going through the object that `handler` returns... you have a function that takes an object and adds a `value` which is a number to it. Unless you have a specific idea of what sort of object this is, to be flexible, use generics so that the return type can be in line with the type passed in. You also probably didn't mean to mutate the object, but return a new object which is a clone of the old object, but with the new value. Use:

```
function setupHandler (config) {
    return { ...config, value: myconst }
}
```

and

```
type SetupHandler = <T extends {}>(config: T) => T & { value: number };
```

`setProcess` calls `setupHandler`, but `setProcess` doesn't use the result of the call, and returns true, which looks like a mistake, but if that's really the code you have, then it's pretty simple...

```
type SetProcess = (config: object) => true;
```

And the `value` is just a number.

Use those types to define the returned object of `handler`.

```
declare const handler: () => {
    setup: SetupHandler;
    process: {
        set: SetProcess;
        options: {
            value: number; // or 10, if specificity is desired
        }
    }
};
```

You can also put the types inline in the returned object type instead of defining them beforehand if you wish.

Comment: Can you check the update? I have made this invalidated now. ` you have a function that takes an object and adds a value which is a number to it`.  Second, I have attached the actual file for the process.js function which needs the .d.ts description. The function is a closure frankly and I want to keep it that way for a reason. How do I associate a return value with nested type structures.

Comment: Second, is there a different way other than `declare const handler: () => {...keys}`. I have done that now. The intellisense shows up that way now. However, it is a big return with nested details `process.js`.  It grossly works. But I am unsure if I nest types (defs) within type (defs). Here is how the real typing looks now. https://github.com/cgi-js/cgi-js/blob/7ffe1aa20afd78d099068dfe03eca7165835b68e/src/process.js#L21